# How to assign a static IP to a device that connect via 2.4 MHz hotspot of NetComm NF18ACV?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dhcp

I want to assign a static IP address for a MAC address of a device that connects via the 2.4 MHz Wi-Fi hotspot.

[image]

When I press 'Apply/Save', I am getting this message:

> #### DHCP Static IP Lease Error
>
> The Broadband Router cannot add the new static IP lease
>   since either the Mac address or the IP address conflict with previous rules.
>   Click on "Back" button to try another static IP configuration.

(manually transcribed; see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15Lvu.png))

Here are my LAN DHCP settings:

[image]

I have tried these as well:

1. Use IP `192.168.20.21`
2. Use dash in the address `9F-FF-FF-FF-AB-D9`

but they all give the same error message above.

Why I am getting this error message? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: It appears you are trying to set a MAC address in your ISP's broadband modem. That is a restriction they would apply. You need to add your own wireless router to be able to restrict by MAC address. Better anyway to restrict access by good (strong) wireless password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netcomm only accept a MAC address with ':' separator.

i.e. I need to eneter `9F:FF:FF:FF:AB:D9`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add a DHCP static lease that is out of the DHCP range. In your DHCP settings, you can see that the range is listed as from 192.168.20.20 - 192.168.20.254, and the address you are trying to assign to the device is 192.168.20.5 which is not in that range. While the address you have specified would be a valid IP address on the network, some routers/gateways will only allow you to add a static lease that is within their own DHCP range.

Comment: I tried 192.168.20.21. Same error message.

Comment: Have you set a static IP for that MAC address before? The only other possible error that I can think of that would be related to that specific error message is if there is a preexisting static lease with that MAC address.